# Python dropbox - Opening spreadsheets

Tags: python, dropbox, xls

I was testing with the dropbox provided API for python..my target was to read a Spreadsheet in my dropbox without downloading it to my local storage.

```
import dropbox
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('my-token')
print dbx.users_get_current_account()
fl = dbx.files_get_preview('/CGPA.xlsx')[1] # returns a Response object
```

After the above code, calling the `fl.text()` method gives an HTML output which shows the preview that would be seen if opened by browser. And the data can be parsed.

My query is, if there is a built-in method of the SDK for getting any particular info from the spreadsheet, like the data of a row or a cell...preferrably in json format...I previously used butterdb for extracting data from a google drive spreadsheet...is there such functionality for dropbox?....could not understand by reading the docs: http://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the Dropbox API doesn't offer the ability to selectively query parts of a spreadsheet file like this without downloading the whole file, but we'll consider it a feature request.